# What is Bayesian PCA and its cousin?

Tags: bayesian, pca, terminology

When I think of the phrase "Bayesian PCA" I think of two things, but these two things are what I have contrived rather than conventional notions. I would appreciate guidance on what these approaches a called.

## Method 1: To eigenstuff from another process

Suppose I model a random data matrix $\mathbf{X}_{m \times n}$ according to some distribution $F_{\mathbf{X}_{m \times n}}$. Then I sample (via Monte Carlo methods) from its posterior and perform an SVD-based PCA on the sample(s). From this we can analyze estimated densities over the principal components.

If someone were to mention "Bayesian PCA" this is what I would guess that they meant (but I don't know).

## Method 2: From eigenstuff into another process

In this approach we **start** from the singular values and orthogonal matrices as the data generating process. That is we would model

$$\Sigma := \nu U E V^*$$

where $U$, $V$ are Haar-distributed random orthonormal matrices (see [Mezzadri 2006](https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0609050v2)) and the diagonal of $E$, denoted $\text{diag}(E)$ follows

$$\text{diag}(E) \sim \text{Dirichlet}(\vec \alpha)$$

and $$\nu \sim \text{Exponential}(\lambda).$$

We could then use $\Sigma$ in a variety of statistical models that have such a positive semi-definite matrix. In this approach the data matrix is generated from the singular stuff rather than the singular stuff being generated from some other process.

## Question

Okay, so outside of my own thoughts and notes, how should I refer to these methods?